# latency density distribution analytics with bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

does any of you know how to build a query with Appengine log bigQuery to get the same result as the latency density distribution which Google analytics gives? Does it make sense to write a query with big query at all or should I use another tool?

Comment: Something like this? SELECT date(metadata.timestamp), NTH(50, QUANTILES(protoPayload.endTime - protoPayload.startTime, 101)) / 1000000,
NTH(75, QUANTILES(protoPayload.endTime - protoPayload.startTime, 101)) / 1000000,
NTH(90, QUANTILES(protoPayload.endTime - protoPayload.startTime, 101)) / 1000000,
NTH(99, QUANTILES(protoPayload.endTime - protoPayload.startTime, 101)) / 1000000

from
TABLE_DATE_RANGE(appengine_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_, 
                 TIMESTAMP('2016-07-10'), TIMESTAMP('2016-08-10')) 
group by 1
order by 1

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with what exactly the Google Analytics latency density distribution you mention is, but from the query it looks like a simple distribution with a subset of the quantiles.

To answer the question, yes, a query similar to the one you wrote will do the task in BigQuery. You probably do not need to compute the quantiles multiple times. You can do it only once in an inner query and select the buckets you want in an outer one.